# Get context and activity (no null) on Fragment inside a setOnCLickListener

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to build a dialog in a fragment using a generic dialog builder that's already part of the project that I am working on. I need to pass a context (non nullable) and an activity(also non nullable) to the Dialog. For that, I am using requireContext() and requireActivity(), but my colleague told me it's dangerous to use the require methods here, since it could cause a crash in production. How could I avoid it?

**See setup() in MyFragment**

GenericDialog.build(**context = requireContext()**, title = string(R.string.my_string_title), content = string(R.string.my_string_msg)).safeShow(**requireActivity()**)

```
class MyFragment : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_my_fr) {
...

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState).also {
    setup()
  }

  private fun setup() {
    binding.myButton.setOnClickListener {
      GenericDialog.build(context = requireContext(), title = string(R.string.my_string_title), content = string(R.string.my_string_msg)).safeShow(requireActivity())
    }
  }
}
```

**safeShow extension function**

```
fun Dialog.safeShow(activity: Activity) = activity.runOnUiThread {
  if (!activity.isFinishing and !this.isShowing and !activity.isDestroyed) {
    show()
  }
}
```

**GenericDialog**

```
object GenericDialog {
  fun build(
    context: Context,
    title: String = "",
    content: String = "",
    acceptButtonTextResId: Int = R.string.general_understood,
    onAccept: () -> Unit = {}
  ): AlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.Dialog)
    .setTitle(title)
    .setMessage(content)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton(acceptButtonTextResId) { dialog, _ ->
      onAccept()
      dialog.dismiss()
    }
    .create()
}
```

Comment: `requireContext()` will crash if `getContext()` would return null ... but if you use `getContext()` and it would return null and you would use it there would be crash anyway ... so as long as you would know the lifecycle `requireContext()` is the way

Comment: is there a way to get a non nullable context?

Comment: it's prolly dangerous for your colleague becuase he doesn't know when to use it

Comment: *is there a way to get a non nullable context?* yes ... guess what ... with `requireContext()`

Comment: off-topic hint: do not use `Dialog` but `FragmentDialog` ... dialogs are the pain in the ass when you come to configuration change activity recreation (like screen rotation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the end was wrapping the Dialog code in a let safe call, so if the activity is null, I don't even show the Dialog.

```
activity?.let { safeActivity -> 
     GenericDialog.build(context = safeActivity, title = string(R.string.my_string_title), content = string(R.string.my_string_msg)).safeShow(safeActivity)
}
```